# How does overlay2 associate container to the folders storing the merged stuff

Tags: image, docker

I am deep diving into overlay2 FS following Docker documentation. 
https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#image-and-container-layers-on-disk-1

It just mentions as of Docker 1.10, it is no longer using the image id to identity image layer.

I could find the container id using command "docker inspect --format {{.Id}} ContainerName`".  In the doc, it mentions we can see the container folder in the directory /var/lib/docker/overlay2 and the image folder within the file "lower-id" of the container folder. However, I could not see the corresponding directory within  /var/lib/docker/overlay2. Instead, there is one in the /var/lib/docker/containers/Container-ID. Currently, I got stuck finding the lower layer(Image) of the container.

The command "find . -name " any filename within the Container" could be used to locate the folder within /var/lib/docker/overlay2, but it is not a good way to see it.

Please help figure out a way to locate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out, you can use docker image inspect ImageName to check the layers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not the best output, but works)

```
TOP_STORAGE=$(du -hs /var/lib/docker/overlay2/* | grep -Ee '^[0-9]{3}[M]+|[0-9]G' | sort -h |tail -n 10 |tee -a /dev/stderr |awk '{print $2}'|xargs|sed 's/ /|/g')

docker inspect $(docker ps -q) | jq '.[]|.Config.Hostname,.Config.Labels."io.kubernetes.pod.name",.GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir,.hovno' | egrep -B2 "$TOP_STORAGE"
```